# Combination of columns in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to combine the column by the following example. The names for the new table are not important.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to merge alternate columns into one column you can use `split.default` with R's recycling property to split them alternately.

```
new_df <- as.data.frame(sapply(split.default(df, c("A", "B")), unlist))
rownames(new_df) <- NULL

new_df
#    A  B
#1   1 11
#2   2 12
#3   3 13
#4   4 14
#5   5 15
#6   6 16
#7   7 17
#8   8 18
#9   9 19
#10 10 20
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 11:15, c = 6:10, d = 16:20)
```

Comment: What if I have columns arranged in this way: `Oct1.1, Oct2.1, Nov1.1, Nov2.1, Oct1.2, Oct2.2, Nov1.2, Nov2.2`?

Comment: @Zizou In that case keep everything else same, replace `split.default` part to `split.default(df, sub("\\d.*", "", names(df)))`

Comment: `as.data.frame(sapply(split.default(df, sub("\\d.*", "", names(df))), unlist))`  after applying your solution, each month is in a separate column.

Comment: it looks now `head(new_df[1:2,1:2])
        Dec Feb
Dec1.11  19  12
Dec1.12   8  10`

Comment: Can you share what is the output of `sub("\\d.*", "", names(df)` ?

Comment: `sub("\\d.*", "", names(ab))
 [1] "Oct" "Oct" "Nov" "Nov"`

Comment: So what is the issue then? `as.data.frame(sapply(split.default(df, sub("\\d.*", "", names(df))), unlist))` doesn't work ?

Comment: The problem is probably here `split.default(df, sub("\\d.*", "", names(df)))` , because I wanted, data frame with two columns "A" and "B" . And now I have as many columns as there are months

Comment: It is not at all clear from your comments what you wanted to do for these new set of columns. Anyway, how would you like to group columns when you have columns like `Oct1.1, Oct2.1, Nov1.1, Nov2.1, Oct1.2, Oct2.2, Nov1.2, Nov2.2` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203663/discussion-between-zizou-and-ronak-shah).

Comment: order for "A" `(Oct1.1, Oct1.2, Nov1.1, Nov1.2), for "B" Oct2.1, Oct2.2, Nov2.1, Nov2.2)`

Answer (score 3):

Another idea is to use boolean indexing on the column, stacking each subset and binding them at the end, i.e. (Using @RonakShah's dataset)

```
setNames(cbind(stack(df[c(TRUE, FALSE)])[1], 
               stack(df[c(FALSE, TRUE)])[1]), 
               c('A', 'B'))
```

which gives,

> ```
>     A  B
> 1   1 11
> 2   2 12
> 3   3 13
> 4   4 14
> 5   5 15
> 6   6 16
> 7   7 17
> 8   8 18
> 9   9 19
> 10 10 20
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Besides the solutions by [@Ronak Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59191202/12158757) and [@Sotos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59191463/12158757), here is another way which gets the alternative column index and form the new data frame

```
idx <- seq(1,ncol(df),by = 2)
data.frame(A=unlist(df[idx]),B=unlist(df[-idx]),row.names = NULL)
```

Comment: What if I have columns arranged in this way: `Oct1.1, Oct2.1, Nov1.1, Nov2.1, Oct1.2, Oct2.2, Nov1.2, Nov2.2`?

Comment: @Zizou I don't think the column name is a issue here....I guess OP just wants to subset the data frame every other column